# Show label as N/A when the data value is null

Tags: javascript, echarts

In Echarts, when data value is null, label formatter function is not triggerred. I want to show lable as N/A for null values.

I tried adding null value and label formatter to this example: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-background
as below :

```
label: {
        show: true,
        color: '#000',
        formatter: function(c){
            console.log(c)
            if(c.value == null) { return 'N/A'}
            return c.value
        }
      }
```

But I noticed that log is not printed when the data value is null.
Is there any way to do it in Echarts?

Answer (score 0):

You want to show label for missing data? But missing data everywhere denoted as nothing, hole, empty space... You cannot to show label for null.

OK, we have workaround for this: just use for `null` unusual big number and apply color style `transparent`.

```js
series: [{
  data: [120, 200, 150, {
    value: 100000,
    itemStyle: {
      color: 'transparent'
    }
  }, 70, 110, 130],
  type: 'bar',
  showBackground: true,
  backgroundStyle: {
    color: 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.8)'
  },
  label: {
    show: true,
    formatter: (c) => c.value != 100000 ? c.value : 'N/A'
  }
}]
```

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    max: 200,
  },
  series: [{
    data: [120, 200, 150, {
      value: 100000,
      itemStyle: {
        color: 'transparent'
      }
    }, 70, 110, 130],
    type: 'bar',
    showBackground: true,
    backgroundStyle: {
      color: 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.8)'
    },
    label: {
      show: true,
      formatter: (c) => c.value != 100000 ? c.value : 'N/A'
    }
  }]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.8.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```